# Stuck on PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, plsqldeveloper

I can't see my error.  I marked the places SQL Developer is citing errors.  Can you see where I am going wrong?  ZCTA5_2000 is a valid table with data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER zip_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON ZCTA5_2000
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  low_zip NUMBER(5);
  high_zip NUMBER(5);  <---  Error PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  ******
BEGIN  <-----Error PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ********

  SELECT LOW_ZIP, HIGH_ZIP FROM ZIPTABLE
  INTO low_zip, high_zip
  WHERE :NEW.STATE = STATE_CODE;  <--- Error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"... 
    IF :NEW.ZIP < LOW_ZIP OR :NEW.ZIP>HIGH_ZIP
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: You must be joking! We will not search in your code for syntax errors.

Comment: Eh, there's plenty here who will.

Comment: You know that zip codes are not unique to states, and that they are not allocated to states by range either, right? And that some zip codes do not relate to states at all.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the line numbers are being reported to you incorrectly. Some front ends will do that.

Note that the `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"` message is three lines too soon. Assuming the same for the `ORA-00933` message means it's really pointing at the `SELECT` statement, and sure enough that's where your error is:

```
SELECT LOW_ZIP, HIGH_ZIP FROM ZIPTABLE
INTO low_zip, high_zip    <== INTO should be before FROM
...
```

The `INTO` has to be after the `SELECT` and *before* the `FROM`. Try changing it to this:

```
SELECT LOW_ZIP, HIGH_ZIP INTO low_zip, high_zip
FROM ZIPTABLE
...
```

Comment: Also a very helpful comment.  Much appreciated.  Not banging my head on the wall anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably more than one mistake:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER zip_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON ZCTA5_2000
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  low_zip NUMBER(5);
  high_zip NUMBER(5);
BEGIN

  SELECT LOW_ZIP, HIGH_ZIP INTO low_zip, high_zip
  FROM ZIPTABLE
  WHERE :NEW.STATE = STATE_CODE;

  IF :NEW.ZIP < LOW_ZIP OR :NEW.ZIP > HIGH_ZIP THEN
    NULL;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Note the rearranged `SELECT` statement (`SELECT...INTO...FROM` instead of `SELECT...FROM...INTO`) and the fixed `IF` statement (`THEN` keyword and dummy statement within the `IF` block).

Comment: Yes.  It compiled error free after changing the select and if as indicated.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`FROM` comes after the `INTO` and a `THEN` is mandatory after `IF` then you should also do something when the `IF` is true.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER zip_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON ZCTA5_2000
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  low_zip NUMBER(5);
  high_zip NUMBER(5);  
BEGIN  
  SELECT LOW_ZIP, HIGH_ZIP
  INTO low_zip, high_zip
   FROM ZIPTABLE
  WHERE :NEW.STATE = STATE_CODE;  
    IF :NEW.ZIP < LOW_ZIP OR :NEW.ZIP > HIGH_ZIP THEN
       null;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Agreed and it compiled after changing.  Thank you